# How can I add local fonts to my react app using font-face

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's my structure :

```
+ src/
++   assets/
+++    fonts/
++++      myfont.ttf
-- index.js
-- App.js
-- App.css
```

I'm adding font face to `_fonts.scss` and importing it to `App.scss`

`_font.scss`

```
$font_dir: "../assets/fonts";

@font-face{
  font-family: 'myfont';
  src: url($font_dir + "myfont.ttf");
}
```

but the problem is I got this error !!

> Module not found: You attempted to import ../assets/fonts/myfont.ttf which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Any help appreciate it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error mention the font should be in the directory of your project (where the package.json is located) or in a subdirectory

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as you see I wrote my structure files, should I change my **$font_dir: "../assets/fonts";** ??

Comment: Yes, the location should be "./assets/fonts" (and be sure that the assets are in the same folder of app.scss)